# Laravel date_format Validation Fails on Textual Month

Tags: php, laravel, date-formatting

My JavaScript library [datepicker](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) returns dates in a format `"March 2019."`

[Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) can decode it.

```php
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('M Y', $request->month);
```

**Laravel** fails on `date_format` validation.

```php
$request->validate([
    'month' => [
        'required',
        'date_format:M Y',
    ],
]);
```

saying

> The month does not match the format M Y.

I have tried all PHP date formats from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)
: M, MM, mm, m.

Comment: you might add following format for your case, `m ([ \t.-])* YY` as manual says it corresponds to `June 2008`.

Comment: You can create custom rule for this if existing rule doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong format. You need to use standard PHP formats, which is what Carbon and Laravel's validation uses. You can find them in the PHP Docs for [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

So change your rule to:

```
date_format:"F Y"
```

Comment: Thank you, it works and especially thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

```
$request->validate([
    'month' => [
        'required',
        'date_format:F Y',
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, I accepted the answer with link and the other anther was posted earlier and accompanied by comment, it is important on this site.